# assign unique tag to based on column value and sequence number

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i have a data frame like this

```
import itertools
import operator
import pandas as pd 
d = {'idx' : [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 
      'names' : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'dd', 'eqq', 'n', 'oo', 'rt', 'xyz', 'yy'], 
      'grp_key' : [4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 7, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4] }
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

Now I want to created group based on column name `grp_key`

```
G = [list(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(df.grp_key.values)]
print(G)
[[4, 4], [5, 5, 5], [7], [8, 8, 8], [4, 4]]
```

or also combine `idx` and `grp_key`

```
gpr_idx = list(zip(df.grp_key.values, df.idx.values))

G = [list(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(gpr_idx, operator.itemgetter(0))]
print(G)
[[(4, 0), (4, 1)], [(5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4)], [(7, 5)], [(8, 6), (8, 7), (8, 8)], [(4, 9), (4, 10)]]
```

I am not able to figure out How to I give unique tag for all repeating group keys. I want df output as below.  for key 4 , I have G1 and G2 because key is same but group is not . How can I do it in more pythonic or pandas way.

```
    idx names  grp_key unique_tag
0     0     a        4       4_G1
1     1     b        4       4_G1
2     2     c        5       5_G1
3     3     d        5       5_G1
4     4    dd        5       5_G1
5     5   eqq        7       7_G1
6     6     n        8       8_G1
7     7    oo        8       8_G1
8     8    rt        8       8_G1
9     9   xyz        4       4_G2
10   10    yy        4       4_G2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple approach could be to increment `G` when the grp_key decreases, using [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
g = df['grp_key'].lt(df['grp_key'].shift()).cumsum().add(1).astype(str)
# or 
# g = df['grp_key'].diff().lt(0).cumsum().add(1)

df['unique_tag'] = df['grp_key'].astype(str).add('_G'+g)
```

Output:

```
    idx names  grp_key unique_tag
0     0     a        4       4_G1
1     1     b        4       4_G1
2     2     c        5       5_G1
3     3     d        5       5_G1
4     4    dd        5       5_G1
5     5   eqq        7       7_G1
6     6     n        8       8_G1
7     7    oo        8       8_G1
8     8    rt        8       8_G1
9     9   xyz        4       4_G2
10   10    yy        4       4_G2
```

If you don't necessarily want this format, the pandas canonical way would be to use:

```
df['unique_tag'] = df['grp_key'].ne(df['grp_key'].shift()).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
    idx names  grp_key  unique_tag
0     0     a        4           1
1     1     b        4           1
2     2     c        5           2
3     3     d        5           2
4     4    dd        5           2
5     5   eqq        7           3
6     6     n        8           4
7     7    oo        8           4
8     8    rt        8           4
9     9   xyz        4           5  # this is a new group
10   10    yy        4           5
```

For the first approach, and assuming a range index, if you only want to increment G on the successive contiguous groups of grp_key:

```
g = (df.groupby('grp_key')['grp_key']
       .transform(lambda g: g.index.to_series().diff()
                             .gt(1).cumsum().add(1)
                             .astype(str))
    )
df['unique_tag'] = df['grp_key'].astype(str).add('_G'+g)
```

Output (with modified input):

```
    idx names  grp_key unique_tag
0     0     a        4       4_G1
1     1     b        4       4_G1
2     2     c        5       5_G1
3     3     d        5       5_G1
4     4    dd        5       5_G1
5     5   eqq        7       7_G1
6     6     n        8       8_G1
7     7    oo        8       8_G1
8     8    rt        8       8_G1
9     9   xyz        4       4_G2
10   10    yy        4       4_G2
11   11    zz        9       9_G1  # G1 since 9 wasn't seen before
12   12   zzz        9       9_G1
```